# Django all-auth Email Required

Tags: django, django-allauth

In my app I need the user to use their email and password to login. Using allauth It creates a registration form where the email field is optional and there is a username field.

I want my registration to have three fields:

- email
- password
- password again

I have tried creating a custom form but it's not working for some reason. I don't know how I can remove the username from the form.

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):        
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', required=True)        
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()       
    def save(self, user):
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.save()
```

It just needs to allow me to register the user correctly and then I can handle the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this was simple, it was just a configuration issue. I added these into the settings file:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'accounts.forms.SignupForm'
```

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question but in case it helps someone in the future, here is what the django-allauth states in its documentation:

> ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD (=”username” | “email” | “username_email”)
>   Specifies the login method to use – whether the user logs in by entering their username, e-mail address, or either one of both.

And

> ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED (=True)
>   The user is required to enter a username when signing up. Note that the user will be asked to do so even if ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD is set to email. Set to False when you do not wish to prompt the user to enter a username.

So in your settings.py you could do this:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

For more information about django-allauth configuration read here: 
[django-allauth documentation - configuration](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `ModelForm` to save and object instance with your form data or you can just use built in `UserCreationForm` more detils [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms):

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("email", "password1", "password2")
```

In your models.py file you should specify `email` field as `username field`. check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser) out

And finally login part. You should write your own custom login view to let users use their emails to login. In your urls put something like this:

```
(r'^email-login/', 'app.views.email_login', name="login"),
```

and `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def email_login(request):
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    try:
        get_user = UserProfile.objects.get(email=email)
    except:
        get_user = None

    user = authenticate(username=get_user, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
```

I didn't test the code but once i've solved my problem with this way. So these may give you some ideas to how to do that. And i believe you can find most of answers you need in this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/)

Comment if you need any extra info.

Comment: I have always had this USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' in my user model. I'm not trying to create some email login, that works just fine. What i'm trying to do is have a username and password for the registration form because by default it has username, email (optional) and password which isn't very useful if the user don't put in an email becauase they cant login.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the accepted answer by Callum, apart from a typo (ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED should be **False**).  I don't have enough points to leave my contribution in the form of a comment, however.  The following works for Django 1.7.

In settings.py:

```
# Sign IN settings
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'

# Sign UP settings
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```