# AssertionError in django-allauth settings.py during Django application startup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm encountering an AssertionError in my Django application when trying to start the development server. The error occurs in the `django-allauth` package, specifically in the `settings.py` file. I've already tried reinstalling `django-allauth`, checking dependencies, and reviewing my configuration without success.

The error occurs with the following change to the configuration options `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'` instead of
`'none'`

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_m
odule
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import app_settings, signals
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\app_settings.py", line 373, in <modu
le>
    app_settings = AppSettings("ACCOUNT_")
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\app_settings.py", line 27, in __init
__
    assert (
AssertionError
```

***My Question:*** How do I fix this error? It shows only when `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` is set to `mandatory`. If it is `none` the project runs smoothly.

Comment: `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'` also requires `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True`.
 Have you set this option as well?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are getting an assertion error, caused by the fact that some settings have requirements for other settings which are not fulfilled.

`ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'` also requires `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True`.

You can see the [documentation](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/configuration.html) for the configuration options and their requirements.

Looking at your error and the source code for django-allauth it seems to be the following requirement that is not fulfilled:

```
# If login is by email, email must be required
        assert (
            not self.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == self.AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL
        ) or self.EMAIL_REQUIRED
```

This further points to the problem being `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` not being set to `True`.
You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27202960/12559207) post for an example of a valid configuration for email verification.

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering is an `AssertionError` in the django-allauth package when you set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` to `'mandatory'`. This error occurs because the django-allauth package expects certain settings to be configured correctly.

To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Ensure you have installed the latest version of django-allauth. You can use the following command to upgrade to the latest version:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade django-allauth
   ```
2. Verify that you have included `'allauth'` and `'allauth.account'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your project's `settings.py` file:

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       # other apps...
       'allauth',
       'allauth.account',
       # other apps...
   ]
   ```
3. Double-check your project's `urls.py` file to ensure that you have included the necessary URLs for django-allauth:

   ```py
   urlpatterns = [
       # other URL patterns...
       path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
       # other URL patterns...
   ]
   ```
4. If you have a custom user model, make sure it is correctly configured in your project's `settings.py` file. You can specify your custom user model using the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting:

   ```py
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.YourCustomUserModel'
   ```
5. Review the other settings related to email verification in your `settings.py` file. Ensure that you have properly configured settings like `EMAIL_BACKEND`, `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED`, and `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`.

   Here's an example configuration for email verification:

   ```py
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
   ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
   ```

   Make sure you have a valid email backend configured that matches your email service provider.
6. If the issue persists, try removing any compiled Python files (.pyc or **pycache**) from your project directory to eliminate any potential caching issues.

I hop it's work